# is there an alternative to query with DELETE snowflake SQL statement with CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-delete, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

On snowflake, is there an alternative to query with DELETE SQL statement with CTE? seems it is not possible.

```
with t as (
select *  from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."CALL_CENTER"
), p as (select t.CC_REC_END_DATE, t.CC_CALL_CENTER_ID , t.CC_REC_START_DATE from t where 1=1 AND t.CC_REC_START_DATE > '2000-01-01')

delete from p
```

For example: if we use a select, we got some results.
[image: CTE with simple SQL select]

but if I use a delete. It shows a syntax error

[image: CTE with delete]

Comment: What SQL DBMS are you using?  Techniques vary depending on this and what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: If you don't want certain records returned in `t`, then don't select them in the CTE. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Under snowflake. I need to delete some rows. The criteria comes from some CTEs

Comment: What's "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error or unexpected outcome?

Comment: Seems an error when  I coded some CTEs then a delete. It is under snowflake.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with this thinking is that SELECT returns some values, that might, or might not be, matching individual records in your table. In principle, they might return even combinations of values from multiple tables, multiple rows, or no rows at all even. What would you want DELETE to do then?

So, for DELETE, you need to specify which rows in the *table* you're operating on are deleted. You can do it with a simple WHERE clause, or with a USING clause.

If you want CTEs with DELETE, the closest would be to use USING, put a subquery there, and join its result with the table. In many cases that's a very useful approach, but it is causing a join, which has a performance impact. Example:

```
delete from CALL_CENTER t
using (
  select cc_call_center_sk from CALL_CENTER
  where 1=1 AND t.CC_REC_START_DATE > '2000-01-01'
) AS sub
where sub.cc_call_center_sk = t.cc_call_center_sk.
```

But again, for your query it doesn't make much sense, and what @cddt wrote is probably your best bet.

Comment: OP has correct syntax for SQL server where you can use simple cte for update and delete.

Answer (score 1):

Hi your example is not very clear but in general yes, you can use a delete statement with a CTE in Snowflake:
For example:

```sql
DELETE FROM YOUR_TABLE USING (
    WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT FIELD1 FROM TABLE1)
        SELECT FIELD1 FROM CTE1
    ) AS CTE_RESULT
WHERE YOUR_TABLE.FIELD1 = CTE_RESULT.FIELD1
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected outcome from the question is not clear, so this is my best interpretation of it.

It seems like you want to delete records from the table `SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCDS_SF100TCL.CALL_CENTER` where the field `CC_REC_START_DATE` is greater than 2000-01-01. If that's what you want to achieve, then you don't need a CTE at all.

```
DELETE FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCDS_SF100TCL.CALL_CENTER t
WHERE t.CC_REC_START_DATE > '2000-01-01'
```