# Deleting Values from a table within CTE

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-delete

I am having trouble replacing the 'Select *' with 'delete' , in my CTE query below. I did not provide example tables because I think/hope this answer can be answered without. Question is how can I delete these records being returned instead of select them - because when I input delete I get the error:

> 'unexpected delete'

How can I delete these records? Mind, when I use 'select *' at the very bottom it works fine.

```
with block_1 as 
(
    select * 
    from table_1
    where col_b is null 
      and col4 || col3 in (select col5 || col6 
                           from table1 
                           group by 1 
                           having count(*) > 1)
),
block_2 as
(
    select * 
    from table1
    where col_b is not null 
      and col4 || col3 in (select col5 || col6 
                           from table_1 
                           group by 1 
                           having count(*) > 1)
)
select *
from table_1 
where col4 || col3 in (select col5 || col6 
                       from table1 
                       group by 1 
                       having count(*) > 1) 
  and misc_id in (select distinct misc_id from table1 
                  where misc_id in (select misc_id from block_1) 
                    and misc_id in (select misc_id from block_2))
  and col_b is null;
```

Comment: This is not easy to understand without an explanation of the logic, along with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Note: this part of the query appears to be outside of any block; `and misc_id in (select misc_id from block_2)`

Comment: @GMB - thx for the note - updated the code

Comment: I don't think that you can use a CTE like you want in Snowflake. The query need to be phrased differently - which requires undersrtand the logic.

Answer (score 2):

Using a CTE and DELETE-operation in combination is simply not possible.

Solution would be rewriting your query and e.g. use the USING clause to avoid the CTE.

You can find more information here [is there an alternative to query with DELETE snowflake SQL statement with CTE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58070845/is-there-an-alternative-to-query-with-delete-snowflake-sql-statement-with-cte) and here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/delete.html

Answer (score 0):

So if we transform you SELECT CTE from IN form to JOIN form, which we can do as your SUB-SELECTs in the INs are pulling distinct values, we can pivot all the code to this form. I have left two IN's in the `main_s1` just for now.

```
WITH block_1_s1 AS (
    SELECT col5 || col6 AS col56
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY 1 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
), block_1 AS (
    SELECT t1.misc_id
    FROM table_1 AS t1
    JOIN block_1_s1 AS t2 
        ON t2.col56 = t1.col4 || t1.col3
    WHERE t1.col_b IS NULL 
), block_2_s1 AS (
    SELECT col5 || col6 as col56
    FROM table_1 
    GROUP BY 1 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
), block_2 AS (
    SELECT t1.misc_id
    FROM table1 AS t1
    JOIN block_2_s1 as t2
        ON t2.col56 = t1.col4 || t1.col3
    WHERE t1.col_b IS NOT NULL 
), main_s1 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT misc_id 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE misc_id IN (select misc_id from block_1) 
        AND misc_id IN (select misc_id from block_2)
)
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_1 AS t1
JOIN block_1_s1 AS t2 
    ON t2.col56 = t1.col4 || t1.col3
JOIN main_s1 as t3 ON t3.misc_id = t1.misc_id
WHERE t1.col_b is null;
```

then to pivot the two INs in the `main_s1` CTE , we need to force uniqueness/distinctness on the misc_id's so we can go from INs (to JOINs)

```
WITH block_1_s1 AS (
    SELECT col5 || col6 AS col56
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY 1 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
), block_1 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.misc_id
    FROM table_1 AS t1
    JOIN block_1_s1 AS t2 
        ON t2.col56 = t1.col4 || t1.col3
    WHERE t1.col_b IS NULL 
), block_2_s1 AS (
    SELECT col5 || col6 as col56
    FROM table_1 
    GROUP BY 1 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
), block_2 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.misc_id
    FROM table1 AS t1
    JOIN block_2_s1 as t2
        ON t2.col56 = t1.col4 || t1.col3
    WHERE t1.col_b IS NOT NULL 
), main_s1 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.misc_id 
    FROM table1 AS t1 
    JOIN block_1 AS b1 ON b1.misc_id = t1.misc_id
    JOIN block_2 AS b2 ON b2.misc_id = t1.misc_id
)
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_1 AS t1
JOIN block_1_s1 AS t2 
    ON t2.col56 = t1.col4 || t1.col3
JOIN main_s1 as t3 ON t3.misc_id = t1.misc_id
WHERE t1.col_b is null;
```

So now the SQL is deduped and all turned into JOINs (we actually could do this in the IN form, I just like JOINs..), we can substitute all the CTE into sub-selects:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_1 AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT col5 || col6 AS col56
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY 1 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t2 
    ON t2.col56 = t1.col4 || t1.col3
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.misc_id 
    FROM table1 AS t1 
    JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT t1.misc_id
        FROM table_1 AS t1
        JOIN ( 
            SELECT col5 || col6 AS col56
            FROM table1 
            GROUP BY 1 
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) AS t2 
            ON t2.col56 = t1.col4 || t1.col3
        WHERE t1.col_b IS NULL 
    ) AS b1 
        ON b1.misc_id = t1.misc_id
    JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT t1.misc_id
        FROM table1 AS t1
        JOIN (
            SELECT col5 || col6 as col56
            FROM table_1 
            GROUP BY 1 
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) AS t2
            ON t2.col56 = t1.col4 || t1.col3
        WHERE t1.col_b IS NOT NULL 
    ) AS b2 
        ON b2.misc_id = t1.misc_id
) as t3 
    ON t3.misc_id = t1.misc_id
WHERE t1.col_b is null;
```

which now can we swapped from SELECT to DELETE just fine.

The main reason I went for JOIN from IN form is the Snowflake in more Sort/Merge based than Row based, and IN is a special form of a JOIN, which if you have indexes (which Snowflake doesn't) can be fast. So given we really are chaining JOINs we have found in our production environment that joins where you pre-distinct the prior stages out performs IN, even though that are the same (when the data has been forced to be safe for the JOIN) but when the optimizing complier fails to see the speed up the JOIN form outperforms the IN (that is not turned into the JOIN form as seen in the profile window).